# ¿Realizar un programa que determinar el numero de placa de un auto?

Tags: java, booleano

```
   int placa;
   char color;
   Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   System.out.println("Ingrese el color del auto: ");
   color = lector.nextLine().charAt(0);
   
   Boolean colorojo = new Boolean(true);
  
  
   System.out.println("Es: " +colorojo);
   
   
   System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de placa del auto: ");
   placa = lector.nextInt();
   
   if (2==4 && 0==1)
     System.out.println("Es taxi.");
   else
     System.out.println("Es auto regular.");
```

Buenas necesito realizar un programa que solicite al usuario que indique si un automóvil es rojo, y el numero de terminación de la placa.
Mi código no funciona como es debido a la hora de compilar.

Ejemplo.

```
Si el automóvil es rojo y la placa termina en 4 o 2.
Entonces el automóvil es un taxi.

Si no.
Entonces el automóvil es regular.

Ejemplo de la pantalla final.
```

```
Computadora : Es el automóvil de color rojo?
Usuario:      true
Computadora: Indique el digito de terminacion de la placa?
Usuario:       4
Computadora: El automovil es un taxi.
```

Comment: ¿Crees que esto evaluará a verdadero en algún momento: `if (2==4 && 0==1)`? Básicamente estás preguntando si 2 es igual a 4 y además 0 es igual a 1. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @JimmyRamirez veo que tiene confusión con respecto a como usar las variables, te he corregido el código con algunos comentarios para que lo compares con tú código inicial y prendas de ello, tu principal problema estaba en las validaciones del `if` porque no evaluabas las variables.

```
Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

//Preguntar color
 System.out.println("¿Es el auto es de color rojo?(true o false): ");
// color = lector.nextLine().charAt(0); esta linea no es necesaria
 System.out.print("usuario: "); // con print se imprime sin salto de linea
 Boolean esColoRojo = lector.nextBoolean();

 //Preguntar terminacion de placa
 System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de placa del auto: ");
 System.out.print("usuario: ");
 int placa = lector.nextInt();

 // la variable esColorRojo se puede evaluar directamente al ser Boolean
 if ((placa == 4 || placa == 2) && esColoRojo)
    System.out.println("Es taxi.");
 else
     System.out.println("Es auto regular.");
```

Pruebas de ejecución:

```
¿Es el auto es de color rojo?(true o false): 
usuario: true
Ingrese el numero de placa del auto: 
usuario: 4
Es taxi.

¿Es el auto es de color rojo?(true o false): 
usuario: false
Ingrese el numero de placa del auto: 
usuario: 1
Es auto regular.
```

Comment: Excelente gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(color == 'R' && (placa == 2 || placa == 4)
{
   //Imprime taxi
}
else
{
   //Imprime regular
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es una condición que va a ser verdadera si el color tiene el valor 'R' y si además se cumple que la placa termina en 2 o 4. Si esta condición no se cumple entonces se ejecuta el else, asumo que en placa estás guardando el último número y no la placa entera, por lo que planteas en tu problema este código debe servirte

Comment: Gracias, pero a la hora de ingresar el numero de placa, siempre me dice que es auto regular, y no me sale en ninguna como taxi.

Comment: Hola Jimmy, se que ya resolviste tu problema pero me gustaría hacerte una aclaración respecto a mi código, el código que te puse si funciona, lo que pasa es que yo asumí que en vez de introducir true tu escribas Rojo y de esta palabra cogias el primer carácter 'R' para verificar el color ya que eso es lo que haces en un fragmento de tu codigo y en base a eso es que te respondí, espero me hayas entendido

Comment: A bueno muchas gracias por la explicacion.